# Are aspects of domain driven design limiting when we scale?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, performance, json, dto

From what I have read about the domain driven design, an aspect of it is that there is a clear separation between domain objects and DTOs.
So the application level components deal with domain objects and are completely unaffected by any changes in the DTOs.
That seems clear win to me but I am wondering if it really scales.
If we have for example a network datasource that sends in a JSON a couple of thousands DTOs and we need to parse them to the json DTOs and then tranform those to the corresponding domain objects thereby having a second list of the domain objects it seems we would spend a significant amount of performance time just converting objects from one type to the other, let alone the fact that the DTOs won't have any use at all in the rest of the application life-cycle till the next fetch.
Am I oversimplifying this or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Realistically the only way to conclude whether something has any impact on performance is to gather metrics which are specific to the application/system in question and analyse those measurements.   Optimisation of any system can only be done effectively after gathering data which identifies specific problems,  So this isn't something that anybody can just make guesses about, and I don't think this question has an answer because performance issues always depend upon specific implementation details..

Comment: That is fair but my question is not about performance of a specific system. I think it is fair to assume that using the DTOs vs `mapping` the DTOs to another set of object is faster since the `mapping` is extra time spend processing objects that in the end of the day they only serve for wire transfer

Comment: It would be good for someone to explain why the downvotes. 4 so far without any comment is not really helping understand what is the problem of the question and if it can be improved or not

Answer (score 4):

DDD is not the problem here, using a distributed system is. In any distributed system, there will be some communication overhead. This is unavoidable. So you generally don't want to build distributed systems (such as microservices) *unless* the problem they solve is bigger than the problems they introduce. For example, if you have so many requests that one server can no longer keep up, you *need* a second server. And if the two servers have to exchange lots of data, that is an acceptable tradeoff.

JSON was developed for ease of use with JavaScript. It's not necessarily the best machine-readable data format. However, native JSON parsers have become *really* fast (on the order of [multiple GB/s](https://simdjson.org/), faster than typical SSDs, faster than most networks). You might also want to use formats that can be transformed into a DTO without any parsing, e.g. Protobuf. (Not really without parsing, but without any extra copies or allocations if you're writing native code). So while serialization overhead exists and can be a [dominant fraction of runtime](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/open-source-technology-insights/a-common-pitfall-with-microservice-architectures/), this is still “good value” for the functionality you're getting.

To avoid communication overhead, there are some patterns for splitting up your services:

- pick appropriate boundaries between services. If tons of data have to be transferred, maybe the responsibilities of the services have not been selected appropriately.
- move the compute to the data, not the data to the compute. A complex SQL statement that returns a single row will likely be faster than moving a GB of data to a fast server. Use read replicas to allow a high query load. Co-locate servers in the same data center, avoid cloud offerings with unspecified geographic distribution.

Comment: You seem to me focused on the server side and optimizing the response size. Assuming that the response is optimal i.e. the data are strictly needed are fetched over the wire and that the JSON parsing is super fast, this still leaves open the question of the benefit of going over a loop to `map` each DTO to a Domain Object and the relative overhead of doing that transformation in relation to the actual retrieval of the DTOs (which as you said might be small clock-wise)

Comment: @Jim Using DTOs is an architectural decision. Usually the right decision, since it insulates your internals from the outside world. But if your performance requirements are at stake? Reusing DTOs as your domain model can be a reasonable approach. Just be aware of the downside, that the system will be more difficult to change in the future: your external data model and internal domain model are effectively fixed, changing one will break the other.

Comment: Yes I understand this. I was trying to understand the design approach using model objects and DTOs. From the descriptions I read it seems like it is:
app <=> [list of domain models] <=> [list of dtos] <=> data source and to me it looks like in a high level perspective that if the fetch of list of dtos is very fast this approach is dominated by the `<loop to transform dtos to domain models>/<fetch dtos>` and in cases of very efficient retrieval the overhad of the transformation seems not justified. I am trying see if I am misunderstanding something